# How were the markings created?

Tags: bodies-tv-series

In the crime/scifi series [*Bodies*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt18347622/), a body, apparently murdered, appears in multiple time periods. One of the noteworthy details is some kind of a marking on the victim's wrist.

> It is revealed the body is that of a time traveller and the marking was not there briefly before the jump. We even witness this on two different time travellers.
>
>  At the same time, the marking appears in the same shape and on the wrist both times, so this can hardly be a naturally occurring side-effect of the time portal used.

I somehow must have missed how that marking was created - **how did it appear on the person's wrist?**

Comment: *Whenever anybody travels through The Throat, it strips them naked (also removing any cyborg tech like Iris’ spinal column) and marks the inside of their wrist with its symbol in the shape of three vertical lines intersected by a fourth horizontal line. That was the shape on Gideon’s wrist when he was discovered as a corpse in all the timelines, the one scratched into the brick in Longharvest Lane by Hillinghead* - https://www.denofgeek.com/tv/bodies-ending-explained-what-the-flip-was-going-on-with-elias-and-the-loop/

Comment: @Valorum: I saw that, but I don't understand it. It's totally believable that a physical phenomenon might transport only certain materials, but not others, but how in the world could it deliberatey leave a specific "symbol" on a particular part of a human body? Is The Throat an intelligent being then? But if I'm not mistaken, no indication is given, in fact, the aspects that it is researched by a *physicist* and the reliance on the duplication effect based on the recognized pattern strongly point to this being a "stupid" natural phenomenon that follows some (albeit totally unknown and ...

Comment: ... thus incomprehensible to the characters) law of nature. The fact that it could deliberately engrave a "symbol" at a specific location of a body, regardless of its posture or size, totally blasts suspension of disbelief for me, unless there's a good explanation there (hence my question) :)

Comment: Based on the fact that it also carefully removes surgical implants and marks the traveler, I'd say that there's got to be some element of design involved

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - The "Throat" sounds very animalistic to me. Not a vortex or a spiral, a wormhole or a funnel, but the throat of some enormous temporal beast.

Comment: @Valorum: Carefully? My impression was that certain materials, including the metal-based (?) implants, simply disappeared during the transfer - and that the protagonist was rather lucky that the implants left just superficial wounds; maybe within the body, there was just some microscopic wiring that did not leave deep wounds. Hence, I perceived the marking as a total outlier in the side-effects of the time travel.

Comment: @Adamant: You mean like they eye of a storm, or the mouth of a river? It would by far not be the first time that a naturally occurring shape on some non-living object is likened to a part of a living being.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Some people might have thought those things were alive (with a river god or a storm god) when they first started referring to them that way! But in any case, real life is not a TV show where names can have plot significance.